# Can't see Folder Content

Tags: files, xampp

I installed XAMMP. When I open /opt from files I can't see the content. But it is exists when typing ls from terminal.

Comment: Well, it may very well be empty. Is this Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 22.04. But I see now when I look from computer. When I look from other medias I can't see.

Comment: Linux mint 20.3  This isn't the right forum is it?